# Comment window show up again after reload

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

After reloading a Question I have commented on Android beta by swiping down from the top, I get the comment box again to the same Answer. It is empty. 
Even when I click on the down arrow to hide the comment box and reload again it reopens.

I believe this didn't happened in the stable channel.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear, can add more information / description into your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! It's fixed as of any version greater than 1.0.81 which should be on the beta tier in the next day or so.